# Which sentece is correct?

Tags: grammar

I consider a healthy lifestyle the most important part of general well-being.
I consider a healthy lifestyle as one of the most important parts of general well-being.

Which sentence is more correct?

Comment: Neither is more correct than the other.

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct but they mean different things.

The first sentence means that there is no other part which is as important as a healthy lifestyle.

The second sentence means that, while there is no part which is more important, there are parts which are equally as important.